# Next.js and AWS Amplify getting Error: No Current User - getServerSideProps

Tags: graphql, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

getServerSideProps is displaying "**No Current User**", but I'm logged in my app.

```
type Post
  @model
  @key(
    name: "postsByUsername"
    fields: ["username"]
    queryField: "postsByUsername"
  )
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "username" }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  username: String
  image: S3Object
}
```

I'm able to use AWS AppSync's website to actually query the posts by username, it returned values. I logged in using the same login I'm in for my app.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const SSR = withSSRContext();
  const { data } = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: postsByUsername,
    variables: {
      username: "username" // checked in dynamodb, same username as signed in. 
    },
    authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
  });
  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.postsByUsername.items,
    },
  };
}
```

I've also added ssr in my **_app.js**:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "../../aws-exports";

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });
```

in **aws-exports.js**:

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "xxxxx",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://...",
    "aws_appsync_region": "xxxxx",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxx-xxxxxxxx...",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "xxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "xxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "xxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxx",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket": "xxxxxx",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region": "xxxxxx"
};
```

everything in awsmobile were autogenerated.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass through the request context in your `withSSRContext` function, so your getServerSideProps function should look as follows

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const SSR = withSSRContext({ req });
  ...
}
```

Reference:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/ssr/q/platform/js/#withssrcontext